# Floppy drive permissions

Tags: permissions, floppy

Why are floppy drive permissions assigned to my 3.5" 1.44 diskette drives in my Ubuntu 12.04.4 and 13.10 operating systems ?

Same floppy drives on these dual boot Ubuntu/Windows machines do not have any permissions assigned under properties in Windows and Windows allows me to read and write perfectly to the diskettes. In the Ubuntu operating systems the properties have a permissions tab, under the permissions tab it says I am not the owner and I can not change the permissions from the current "ROOT". It will not let me write to the diskette with my administrator profile.(excuse me! but I am the owner of all the content on my floppy diskettes).
I know enough to know that "USER" usage of a floppy diskette on a personal computer is identical to permissions associated with a common flash drive (i.e. pen drive).

How do I remove the lockout permissions on the floppy drive to be able to write to it?

Answer (score 0):

You were able to get Ubuntu to read and write floppies?  Good job! I've tried and have not succeeded.  When I need to change file permissions, I use Nautilus/Files in SUDO mode. I know people caution about using Nautilus as SUDO/root. I just make sure I'm making changes to the correct file in the correct folder. To change file permissions using Nautilus, just right-click the file in question, select 'properties' then click the 'permissions' tab.